# Read 8 bit or 16 or 32 bit from address in C language

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define READ8(Address)  \
            (*((volatile long *)(Address)))
int main()
{
   int Array[2]; 
   long out_value;
   Array[0] = 55;
   Array[1] = 66;
   out_value = READ8(&Array[0]);
   printf("%d\n", out_value);
}
```

I am trying to read 8 bit data, 16 bit data and 32 bit data and store in out_value variable. i am changing reading size of data type by changing the data type in Macro as int / long but every time out put is printed as 55 only.

i want to print as 55 and also 5566.

Comment: I don't understand what do you want to do. Could you post a better example?

Comment: What system are you running this on?

Comment: int is not 8 bits, you can use unsigned char for 8 bits, even than outvalue won't print 5566

Comment: What is your actual use case for this? In the example code currently given, you could just index the array directly without any cast or macro. If you want the `55` and `66` to occupy adjacent bytes in memory, the elements of `Array` (which should probably be called `array`) should be `uint8_t` instead of`int`, and then I see no reason why you are casting it to `volatile long *` in the macro (and it may not be correctly aligned for such a cast). Also, if `out_value` is `long`, the format should be `%ld`.

Comment: Even if you want to read 8, 16 or 32 bit, an int value (which size is 32bit) =< 255 return the same value.

Comment: You'll need to provide more information on what you're attempting to do.  If you're reading from hardware at a fixed address, you should declare a constant pointer of the appropriate type, e.g. `uint8_t *const status_register = 0xa0;` or similar.

Comment: Actually i want store values in consecutive memory location as 123456 and need to access 8 bit as 56 and 16 bit as 3456 and 32 bit as 123456 in one shot. i think some how i clearly explain what it need ..

Answer (score 0):

Casting between pointer types is not portable, and will break horribly due to unaligned access or to compiler optimisations.  The (reasonably) portable way is to use memcpy:

```
unsigned int a[1000] = {...};
unsigned long long x;
memcpy(&x, &a[57], sizeof(unsigned long long))
```

Don't worry about the extra function call — both gcc and clang will recognise this pattern and optimise the call to `memcpy` away.

Comment: MSVC won't optimize this, or at least I've never seen it do so. Another reasonably portable approach would be to read the full native-width value, and then mask it off as appropriate to fit into a smaller type. *All* compilers are guaranteed to generate efficient code for that.

Comment: The question was about copying data from a smaller to a larger type.

Comment: I thought that was obvious. The compiler will do extension just fine for scalar types; this is well-defined behavior. There is only a problem if, as you mentioned, you try to cast between *pointer* types.

Comment: Actually i am working with controller so i will copy the values from address of micro controller. can't use memcpy keyword. Please provide alternate solution of that.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously what you were after wasn't meant to be portable. Your observations revealed that `int` and `long` have the same size (most probably 4 byte) in your environment, and are stored in little-endian byte order. You seem to think `sizeof(int)` were 2 when you define `int Array[2]`; if you want a data type with a certain size, you should use the standard types from `<stdint.h>`, for 16 bits this would be `int16_t` instead of `int`.

> i want to print as 55 and also 5566

If you read the two consecutive 16-bit words `(int16_t []){55, 66}` into a 32-bit `long` on your *controller*, the resulting value cannot be 5566, but rather 4325431 (55 + 66 × 0x10000).